# Fetching last photo taken with Swift

Tags: swift, phasset, photosframework

I will start by saying I am new to swift, as well as stack overflow, so I apologize if I mess anything up.

I am trying to fetch the last photo taken with Swift. I found code that seems like it should work. 
http://blog.swilliams.me/words/2015/08/09/finding-the-last-photo-taken/

```
import UIKit
import Photos

typealias ImageCallback = (UIImage? -> Void)

func fetchLastPhoto(resizeTo size: CGSize?, imageCallback: ImageCallback) {
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
fetchOptions.fetchLimit = 1

if let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: fetchOptions) {
    if let asset = fetchResult.firstObject as? PHAsset {
        let manager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()
        let targetSize = size == nil ? CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth, height: asset.pixelHeight) : size!
        manager.requestImageForAsset(asset,
            targetSize: targetSize,
            contentMode: .AspectFit,
            options: nil,
            resultHandler: { image, info in
            imageCallback(image)
        })
    } else {
        imageCallback(nil)
    }
  }
}
```

I keep getting an error on the line that starts "`if let fetchResult = PHAsset.fet....`"

The error says, "

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not
>   'PHFetchResult'

When I option click on "`fetchResult`", it doesn't tell me what type of value it is and gives and error, so I know it is not getting set correctly.

I feel like the solution is probably something really simple that I have not tried yet.

Does anybody have any idea what is causing this error?

Answer (score 4):

Check the declaration of `PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(_:options:)` method. (Quick Help would work enough.)

```
class func fetchAssetsWithMediaType(mediaType: PHAssetMediaType, options: PHFetchOptions?) -> PHFetchResult
```

The return type of the method is `PHFetchResult`, which does not have a trailing `?`, meaning it it not Optional.

You cannot use non-Optional type as a right hand side of optional binding, and this is what the error message is saying. And it also means **you have no need to check the nullability using `if-let`**.

Just remove the `if-let` causing the error and replace it to a simple `let` declaration.

```
func fetchLastPhoto(resizeTo size: CGSize?, imageCallback: ImageCallback) {
    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
    fetchOptions.fetchLimit = 1

    let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: fetchOptions)
    //`fetchResult` is not nil here (without using `if-let`)
    if let asset = fetchResult.firstObject as? PHAsset {
        let manager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()
        let targetSize = size == nil ? CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth, height: asset.pixelHeight) : size!
        manager.requestImageForAsset(asset,
                                     targetSize: targetSize,
                                     contentMode: .AspectFit,
                                     options: nil,
                                     resultHandler: { image, info in
                                        imageCallback(image)
        })
    } else {
        imageCallback(nil)
    }
}
```